# jetty server executing php

Tags: php-fpm, jetty

I want to configure so that jetty runs PHP files, but have been unsuccessful so far. I have Jetty WTP tools installed in my Eclipse IDE.

When I start up the Jetty server. I got the exception: **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException org.mortbay.servlet.CGI: org.mortbay.servlet.CGI** and **javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.mortbay.servlet.CGI**. I put a simple php file(index.php) under my WebContent folder. I also downloaded this library and added it to the classpath(Eclipse: build path and add external jar). I have no clue now what I've done wrong. I also compiled php with:

```
./configure --with-fastcgi=/usr/local
make
sudo make install
```

And my web.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Sample PHP Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>PHP</servlet-name>  
        <servlet-class>org.mortbay.servlet.CGI</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>commandPrefix</param-name>
            <param-value>/usr/local/bin/php-cgi-fix</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>PHP</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/index.php/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.php</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list> </web-app>
```

It could be my php-cgi-fix file, I got the followig text i terminal when i open it:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/php-cgi-fix ; exit;
/usr/local/bin/php-cgi-fix: line 3: /usr/bin/php-cgi: No such file or directory
logout
```

Shouldn't be /usr/local/php-cgi instead? Ok I tried that now, but still I got the same ecxeptions when I launch the server.

(I really don't like to use maven too

Comment: add output "ls -al /usr/bin/php-cgi"

Answer (score 0):

Install php-cgi(contain /usr/bin/php-cgi).

Ubuntu/Debian:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cgi
```

CentOS/Red Hat/Fedora:

```
yum install php-cli
```

In Mac OS try create symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php-cgi
```

Comment: you have missunderstood me. I want jetty to be able to run php code not only java

Comment: For run PHP code you need install PHP

Comment: yeah I've already done that. But configuring the servlet and server is the next step which I'm in

Comment: add output "ls -al  /usr/bin/php-cgi" and what your OS?

Comment: I'm conifguring the server on my mac. but the php is working I think. It is the server who isn't

Comment: I will sooner deploy it on the remote server

Comment: But adding the library si correct isn't it? Little odd that class is not found?

Comment: Try create symlink `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php-cgi`

Answer (score 0):

If your php-cgi-fix script comes from [Jetty and PHP](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Jetty+and+PHP) then it is no longer required, you can just call php-cgi directly.

22 days after you asked the question but if you are still not there then I'd suggest getting this running outside of Eclipse first. Enable debugging and look for lines in the log containing "CGI" and also set init_param "ignoreExitState" to "true".

Questions about Jetty and PHP come up about once a year on the mailing list so my guess is very few people are doing this. You may well be the first to do this on a Mac with a particular version of Jetty.